# filter woocommerce_upsells_total doesn't return a integer

Tags: php, woocommerce, timber, php-8.1

I'm stuck on a fatal error with my Woocommerce theme. It al started when we switched from PHP 7.4 to 8.1. We get the following error when we go to a product page:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: array_slice(): Argument #3 ($length) must be of type ?int, array given in F:\Websites\rewave\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php:2087 Stack trace: #0 F:\Websites\rewave\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php(2087): array_slice(Array, 0, Array) #1 F:\Websites\rewave\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(307): woocommerce_upsell_display(Array) #2 F:\Websites\rewave\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(331)

The problem can be fixed if i go to the plugins folder and in plugins > woocommerce > includes > wc-template-function.php and change filter 'woocommerce_upsells_total' in the function 'woocommerce_upsell_display' like this:

Original code:

```
$limit   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_total', isset( $args['posts_per_page'] ) ? $args['posts_per_page'] : $limit );
```

Fix:

```
$limit   = (int)apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_total', isset( $args['posts_per_page'] ) ? $args['posts_per_page'] : $limit );
```

The only problem is i do not want to change core woocommerce files. Is their any way to fix this without changing the main woocommerce files?

We use this code for creating the twig content:

```
/* Single product */
$context['post']    = Timber::get_post();
$product            = wc_get_product( $context['post']->ID );
$context['product'] = $product;

// Get related products
$related_limit               = wc_get_loop_prop( 'columns' );
$related_ids                 = wc_get_related_products( $context['post']->id, $related_limit );
$context['related_products'] =  Timber::get_posts( $related_ids );

// Restore the context and loop back to the main query loop.
wp_reset_postdata();
Timber::render( 'templates/woocommerce/product.twig', $context );
```

**Details about our theme:**

- Made with Timber & Twig
- Woocommerce 7.0.0
- PHP 8.1

**What i tried:**

- Updating Woocommerce manually
- Removing all content from the php file so only the post is retreived (still gives the error)
- Tried to overwrite the function 'woocommerce_upsell_display'

Comment: I'd suggest that you open a ticket with the support for this issue

Comment: Will do, i thought i did something wrong and that the issue was from my end not theirs.

Comment: When I googled I saw some other tickets concerning `PHP 8.1`, seems they are still converting their codebase

Comment: I currently fixed it by removing the upsells hook. I have also had contact with Woocommerce support but the can not help me because the think that it is something in my theme. I looked everywhere but we did absolutly nothing to change the product upsells or anything related to that hook.

Comment: If you don't think it's your theme, then you try to activate the default theme and enable the plugin again. This way you can check if the errors still occurs on the default theme, if so report back to the support

Comment: Sorry forgot the say but i tried that already and the default theme works. It could be or theme but we did not change anything related to that hook in the theme. I don't know which hooks use the 'woocommerce_upsells_total' expect 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' so i can not pin point the exact location of the error. And the fatal error als is not giving the location of the exact error (for example the function.php or something) so i do not know where to start looking in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Did you correctly added the timber_set_product function to your theme in functions.php ?

Had the same issue due to typo with this code.

```
 function timber_set_product( $post ) {
    global $product;

    if ( is_woocommerce() ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. Switching back to 7.4 fixed the issue. The (int) fix also works

```
$limit   = (int)apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_total', isset( $args['posts_per_page'] ) ? $args['posts_per_page'] : $limit );
```

To avoid change core woocommerce files you can add the whole function to your functions.php file

```
function woocommerce_upsell_display( $limit = '-1', $columns = 4, $orderby = 'rand', $order = 'desc' ) {
    global $product;

    if ( ! $product ) {
        return;
    }

    // Handle the legacy filter which controlled posts per page etc.
    $args = apply_filters(
        'woocommerce_upsell_display_args',
        array(
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'orderby'        => $orderby,
            'order'          => $order,
            'columns'        => $columns,
        )
    );
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'name', 'up-sells' );
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_columns', isset( $args['columns'] ) ? $args['columns'] : $columns ) );

    $orderby = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_orderby', isset( $args['orderby'] ) ? $args['orderby'] : $orderby );
    $order   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_order', isset( $args['order'] ) ? $args['order'] : $order );
    $limit   = (int)apply_filters( 'woocommerce_upsells_total', isset( $args['posts_per_page'] ) ? $args['posts_per_page'] : $limit );

    // Get visible upsells then sort them at random, then limit result set.
    $upsells = wc_products_array_orderby( array_filter( array_map( 'wc_get_product', $product->get_upsell_ids() ), 'wc_products_array_filter_visible' ), $orderby, $order );
    $upsells = $limit > 0 ? array_slice( $upsells, 0, $limit ) : $upsells;

    wc_get_template(
        'single-product/up-sells.php',
        array(
            'upsells'        => $upsells,

            // Not used now, but used in previous version of up-sells.php.
            'posts_per_page' => $limit,
            'orderby'        => $orderby,
            'columns'        => $columns,
        )
    );
}
```